# Why can't I use Stream#toList to collect a list of a class' interface in Java 16?

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, type-inference, java-16

I'm streaming objects of a class implementing an interface. I'd like to collect them as a list of elements of the interface, rather than the implementing class.

This seems impossible with Java 16.0.1's `Stream#toList` method. For example in the code below, the last statement will fail to compile.

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class WhyDodo {

    private interface Dodo { }

    private static class FancyDodo implements Dodo { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Dodo> dodos = Stream.of(new FancyDodo()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        final List<FancyDodo> fancyDodos = Stream.of(new FancyDodo()).toList();

        final List<Dodo> noFancyDodos = Stream.of(new FancyDodo()).toList();
    }
}
```

We could explicitly cast each element from `FancyDodo` to `Dodo`. But at least for brevity, we could just as well use `.collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Why can't I use Stream#toList to collect a list of a class' interface in Java 16?

And if anyone has a better solution than explicitly casting, I'd be happy to hear as well :)

Comment: Try `Stream.<Dodo>of(new FancyDodo())`. With that factory method, you get `Stream<FancyDodo>`, which is not compatible with `Stream<Dodo>`

Comment: Interesting question, as an end-user I would have expected it to behave more like the `.collect(Collectors.toList())` unless the documentation could call that out. Another interesting line is `final List<Dodo> fancyDodosAgain = Arrays.asList(Stream.of(new FancyDodo()).toArray(Dodo[]::new))`

Comment: Because it returns a `List<T>`, where `T` is whatever it is a stream of.  If you want a more abstract type, that's easy: `List<Dodo> dodos = fancyDodos.stream().map(d -> (Dodo) d).toList()`

Comment: Alternately, you could say: `List<? extends Dodo> = fancyDodos.stream().toList()`, since a `List<FancyDodo>` is a `List<? extends Dodo>`.

Comment: @Naman that’s just another case of the impossibility to declare that a method may return a broader type than another type parameter (hypothetical `<U super T> List<U> toList()`). This syntax does not exist because when Generics were introduced, the creators thought that this was rarely needed. It works with `collect`, because the `toList` collector introduces its own type variable which gets mapped to the Stream’s type parameter with a `super` bound at the `collect` call. Edit: oh, just saw [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67517262/#comment119348250_67517411)…

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`.collect(Collectors.toList())` works because the signature of `collect` is:

```
<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector);
```

the important part being `? super T`

which means the `toList()` collector can be interpreted as `Collector<Dodo,?,List<Dodo>` (when you assign the result of `.collect()` to a `List<Dodo>`) even though the type of your stream is `Stream<FancyDodo>`.

On the other hand, the signature of `Stream`'s `toList()` is:

```
List<T> toList()
```

so if you execute it for a `Stream<FancyDodo>`, you'll get a `List<FancyDodo>`, which can't be assigned to a `List<Dodo>` variable.

I suggest you simply use `stream.collect(Collectors.toList())` instead of `stream.toList()` in this case.

Comment: follow up to the authors if they reach out here, can we try to make it similar in behavior with `Collectors.toList`?

Comment: I should have mentioned JDK authors. But let the comment be if they happen to visit. I also now realize that the first impedance in making it work might be the underlying call to `toArray` that is for certain reasons considered in (default)implementation for the performance of this API. But to add to the questions, the implementation for e.g. `ReferencePipeline` could still do away with that `return SharedSecrets.getJavaUtilCollectionAccess().listFromTrustedArrayNullsAllowed(this.toArray(Object[]::new));`... maybe?

Comment: @Naman Unfortunately there's no way to do this. You might think something like `<U super T> List<U> toList()` would work, but alas, having `super` in that type bound is illegal.

Answer (score 20):

Because [`Stream.toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) is declared to return a `List<T>`:

```
default List<T> toList() { ... }
```

where `T` is the element type of the stream. I can't really think of an alternative way of declaring `toList` so that it can return your desired type of list. The best you can do is to accept a `List<? super T>` as *argument*, and add the stream elements to it, but that kind of goes against the "aesthetics" of streams - the whole point of this is to be declarative and have little state.

One way you can rewrite *your code* to make `toList` return a list of your desired type, is to specify the type of `T` manually. Right now `T` is inferred to be `FancyDodo` due to `Stream.of(new FancyDodo())`, but you can force `T` to be `Dodo` if you want:

```
Stream.<Dodo>of(new FancyDodo()).toList();
```

Now `T` is `Dodo`, `toList` will return a `List<Dodo>`.

---

> The best you can do is to accept a `List<? super T>` as *argument*, and add the stream elements to it

Actually, this is kind of what `Collector` is doing. Notice how `collect` accepts a `Collector<? super T, DoesntMatter, R>`, and returns `R`. That contravariant `? super T` is what enables you to use a `toList` collector like that. Note also that `R` is a generic parameter of `collect`, which means that *you get to decide what `collect` returns*, as long as you can provide a collector that collects `? super T` to `R`.

Comment: "I can't really think of an alternative way of declaring toList so that it can return your desired type of list."
Surely `default <R super T> List<R> toList()` would work?

Comment: Wait, since when can you use `super` in generic constraints!? Is that a Java 16 feature? @MikeFHay

Comment: Since Generics were introduced in Java 5. It's in the type signature for `collect`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)

Comment: @MikeFHay Did you confuse wildcards with generic constraints? `collect` uses a wildcard `? super T`, but your suggested signature uses `super T` as a generic constraint. You can do `default List<? super T> toList()`, sure, but not `default <R super T> List<R> toList()`. Did you try writing such a method yourself? I get an "unexpected token" error.

Comment: I guess I am confused. You're right, I can't get it to work either. I was not aware of this limitation of generics.

Answer (score 8):

Generic type argument resolution happens one method call at a time.

`Stream.of(new FancyDodo())` will *always* resolved `T` to `FancyDodo`, so will always result in a `Stream<FancyDodo>`.

`toList()` doesn't resolve `T`, it just uses the already-established `T`, so the result is *always* `List<FancyDodo>`, and `List<FancyDodo>` is not compatible with `List<Dodo>`. See: "[Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/5221149)"

`collect(Collectors.toList())` has a different `T` in the [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()), that can resolve differently from the `T` of the `Stream`. The compiler resolves that `T` as `Dodo`, because of the desired return type of `List<Dodo>`.